# Eclipse RCP: Calling perspectiveChanged leads to stackoverflow

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application which I am migrating from Eclipse 3.0 to 4.4, which works fine so far. Due to the migration, some menue entries (e.g. generic open file) were added, which I want to remove. This works so far, because I am calling `hideActionset(...)` in my `perspectiveActivated()` methods.

The menu entries disappear. But when I reset the perspective and then change the perspective, the menu entries appear again. I tried to fix this by calling `hideActionSet(...)` in my `perspectiveChanged(...)` methods, but they get called so often that I get a stackoverflow.

```
    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveListener#perspectiveActivated(org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage, org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveDescriptor)
     */
    public void perspectiveActivated(IWorkbenchPage page, IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective) 
    {
        if( perspective.getId().equals(m_PerspektivenID) || m_PerspektivenID.equals(STANDARDAKTION))
        {
            setEnabled( true );
        }
        else
        {
            setEnabled( false );
        }

        if(page != null)
        {
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.keyBindings");
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveListener#perspectiveChanged(org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage, org.eclipse.ui.IPerspectiveDescriptor, java.lang.String)
     */
    public void perspectiveChanged(IWorkbenchPage page, IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective, String changeId) 
    {
        if(page != null)
        {
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.keyBindings");
            page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles");
        }
    }
```

Here's a snipped of one of the two log-files that are being generated:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 4 0 2016-01-12 14:37:00.768
!MESSAGE Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/UIElement/widget/SET] to handler org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler@faec277
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.util.HashMap.containsKey(HashMap.java:595)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.containsKey(Collections.java:2578)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.services.ContextContextService.setEventCaching(ContextContextService.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.services.ContextContextService.deferUpdates(ContextContextService.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.contexts.ContextService.deferUpdates(ContextService.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.removeActionSet(Perspective.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.hideActionSet(WorkbenchPage.java:2593)
    at packagenane.classname.perspectiveChanged(BaseAction.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList$4.run(PerspectiveListenerList.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.fireEvent(PerspectiveListenerList.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.firePerspectiveChanged(PerspectiveListenerList.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.firePerspectiveChanged(WorkbenchWindow.java:1721)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.hideActionSet(WorkbenchPage.java:2596)
    at packagenane.classname.perspectiveChanged(BaseAction.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList$4.run(PerspectiveListenerList.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.fireEvent(PerspectiveListenerList.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.firePerspectiveChanged(PerspectiveListenerList.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.firePerspectiveChanged(WorkbenchWindow.java:1721)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.hideActionSet(WorkbenchPage.java:2596)
    at packagenane.classname.perspectiveChanged(BaseAction.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList$4.run(PerspectiveListenerList.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.fireEvent(PerspectiveListenerList.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.firePerspectiveChanged(PerspectiveListenerList.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.firePerspectiveChanged(WorkbenchWindow.java:1721)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.hideActionSet(WorkbenchPage.java:2596)
    at packagenane.classname.perspectiveChanged(BaseAction.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList$4.run(PerspectiveListenerList.java:134)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace you can clearly see that when you call `WorkbenchPage.hideActionSet` a new perspective changed event is being fired and `perspectiveChanged` is being called again while you are still in the first `perspectiveChanged` call.

One way to stop this is to have a flag in your `perspectiveChanged` method to detect that you are already dealing with a change.

Something like:

```
private boolean changeActive;

public void perspectiveChanged(IWorkbenchPage page, IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective, String changeId) 
{
  if (changeActive) {   // Don't do anything if already handling change
    return;
  }

  changeActive = true;

  if (page != null)
    {
        page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.keyBindings");
        page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles");
    }

  changeActive = false;
}
```